# javascript: Why does obj.constuctor.name give 2 different results if prototype is missing?

Tags: javascript, classname

Why does obj.constuctor.name give 2 different results if prototype is missing? How do i get the constructor name instead of "Object" if it has prototype then?

```
// Class with prototype
function Foo(a) {
    this.a = a;
}
Foo.prototype = {
    bar: function () {
        console.log(this.a);
    }
};
f=new Foo(1)
f.constructor.name
"Object"

// Class with no prototype
function Fooee(a) {
    this.a = a;
}

f1=new Fooee(1)
f1.constructor.name
"Fooee"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're changing the constructor of `Foo()` by redefining its prototype to object `{}`.

You should've instead done this:

```
Foo.prototype.bar = function () {
   console.log(this.a);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Functions’ `prototype` properties have initial values that include `constructor`. You can try it:

```
function Foo() {
}

assert(Foo.prototype.constructor === Foo);
```

When you overwrite the entire `prototype` with an object, you’re clobbering that property. (`{}.constructor === Object`.) Just assign new properties to it instead:

```
Foo.prototype.bar = function () {
    console.log(this.a);
};
```